# Read RealtimeDatabase without listeners

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I doesn't understand how is it so difficult read a data from Firebase RealtimeDatabase in an instant. I think there is no other way than use listeners. In my code i want to read the filed 'tipo' from an object user and print on screen. But it doesn' load the data

```
 private User user;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mDatabaseAPI = FirebaseRealTimeDatabaseAPI.getInstance();
    setFields();
    Toast.makeText(this,user.getTipo(),Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();

}
private void setFields() {
        Authentication auth = new Authentication();
        user = new User();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        reference = mDatabaseAPI.getUserReferenceByUid(user.getUid()).child(user.TIPO);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user.setTipo( dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're calling Toast to show your message before firebase finished loading your data, it's an async call, you have to do something like this

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user.setTipo( dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class));
            Toast.makeText(this,user.getTipo(),Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
        }
```